# What is the meaning of $R\textbf{e}_r$?

Tags: notation

I am reading Nolting's *Theoretical Physics, 1*. Here:

> [image]

$\textbf{r}(t)$ is a function of $t$ but it appears nowhere in the expression. Going back, we find:

> [image]

In which $t$ appears in the formula. Which also points to:

> [image]

And a little bit back, I found:

> [image]

Which is akin to what I was expecting to see for circular motion. It's not clear what he means with $R \textbf{e}_r$, perhaps he doesn't want to choose an specific coordinate system? But then, he seems to be pointing to the basis vector defined at $1.371$, I am very confused.

Comment: $e_r$ is unit vector in the radial direction in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what you have :

> **Circular motion**
>
> $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is a function of $t$ but it appears nowhere in the expression.
>
> $$\mathbf{r}(t) = R \mathbf{e}_r$$

So $\mathbf{r}(t)$ does appear.

Circular motion tells us that the radius is constant, hence we can use a constant $R$ as a scalar multiple of the radial vector $\mathbf{e}_r$.  That is $r(t)=R$ in equation (2.8).

> It's not clear what he means with $R\mathbf{e}_r$, perhaps he doesn't want to choose an specific coordinate system ?

This *is* the use of the polar coordinate system. What seems to be confusing you is the use of the polar coordinate basis vectors (like $\mathbf{e}_r$).